# openCV matching two object python and tracking

Tags: python, opencv, tracking, matching

I have image with my object  [image]
and my object
 [image]

when i execute my code

```
    import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("c.mp4")
while(True):
    ret, img_rgb = cap.read()
    img_rgb = img_rgb[400:1200,10:1000]
    img_rgb = cv2.imread('ccc.jpg')
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.imread('job/ff2.jpg',0)
    w, h = template.shape[::-1]
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = 0.8
    loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        print("yes")
        cv2.rectangle(img_gray, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)

    cv2.imshow('res.png',img_gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.waitKey(0)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My object is detected 
[image]

but when i use video its not find my object in video https://youtu.be/O1IB0dnDrWw

Any help please

Comment: Template match works perfect only when the object is  neither scaled nor rotated, that is the object template image is `pixwise-same` with the target in the scene. In video, the condition may not match, so failed.

Comment: thank you, But how i can detect the object in the video, I can't use the mask because a i have lot of object to detect with lotof color

Comment: deep learning convolutional neural networks and enough training data.

Comment: you have reson but i tested by tensorflow but i have similary object deep learning is browren with similary object and i need same thing more basic